# Creación de una web con nodejs de forma pública

Tags: nodejs, web, servidor, ubuntu-server

He estado creando una web en nodejs y me gustaría hostearla de forma pública. La subiría a un host, pero aprovecho que tengo un servidor a mano para alojarla ahí.
Me gustaría saber si alguien me podría detallar el proceso de hacer la web pública, es decir, que pueda acceder a ella fuera de mi entorno (red de casa).

He visto que hay opciones con Ngrok y otras abriendo puertos en el módem.
¿Cuál es mejor y que ventajas tienen?

Gracias de antemano y un saludo.

*PD: A ser posible me gustaría que fuera HTTPS, osea que tenga certificado SSL.*